# error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I want to create a new  project with this command .

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

project is created but there is some issue with the bundler.

```
✖ Installing Bundler

error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/ismail/Dropbox/My Mac (Muhammad’s MacBook

Pro)/Desktop/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby -I

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r

./siteconf20230524-7627-1owxb3s.rb extconf.rb

checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi... no

checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi... no

checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi-8... no

checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS... no

checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes

creating extconf.h

creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/ismail/Dropbox/My Mac (Muhammad’s MacBook

Pro)/Desktop/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c

make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/ismail/Dropbox/My Mac (Muhammad’s MacBook

Pro)/Desktop/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c

make "DESTDIR="

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

make: *** ["/Users/ismail/Dropbox/My] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ismail/Dropbox/My Mac (Muhammad’s

MacBook Pro)/Desktop/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for

inspection.

Results logged to /Users/ismail/Dropbox/My Mac (Muhammad’s MacBook

Pro)/Desktop/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-22/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in

`run'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in

`block in make'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in

`each'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in

`make'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in

`block in build'

  /Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tempfile.rb:291:in `open'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:30:in

`build'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:169:in

`block in build_extension'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in

`synchronize'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in

`build_extension'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in

`block in build_extensions'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in

`each'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in

`build_extensions'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:844:in

`build_extensions'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in

`build_extensions'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in

`install'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:198:in

`install'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in

`install'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in

`install_from_spec'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in

`do_install'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in

`block in worker_pool'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in

`apply_func'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in

`block in process_queue'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in

`loop'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in

`process_queue'

/Users/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in

`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:

  cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on

    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on

      typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on

        ethon was resolved to 0.16.0, which depends on

          ffi

✖ Installing Bundler

error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.

Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.

    at createFromTemplate (/Users/ismail/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:131:11)

    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/ismail/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:184:3)

    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/ismail/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I have tried install cocopods gem nodejs and many more commands even i tried documentation but still error

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code, etc.

Comment: Oh, come on. Please put *some* effort in your question if you want a decent answer from the community.

Comment: Doesn't follow stackoverflow guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands fixed my error

```
brew install libffi

ln -s $(brew --cellar libffi)/*/include/ffi.h /usr/local/include/ffi.h

ln -s $(brew --cellar libffi)/*/include/ffitarget.h /usr/local/include/ffitarget.h
```

referred to this thread: **ffi/ffi#814 (comment)**

Comment: Referred to https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1832#issuecomment-1552264615

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).